# Inverse image of the set $[−1, 4)$ under $f : x \mapsto -x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse

I have an issue with determining the inverse image of a set. I cannot understand anything about it. I've got a simple exercise here, could someone here show me how the inverse image works and more importantly, why?

> There is a function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, f(x) = −x^2$. Find the inverse image of the set $[−1, 4)$.

Comment: The question is, "For what values of $x$ is $f(x)$ in $[-1,4)$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse image of $A=[-1,4)$ under $f$ is 
$$ \{x \in \Bbb R \mid -1 ≤ f(x) = -x^2 < 4 \} $$

Then you have to solve w.r.t. $x$ the following inequations : $1≥x^2>-4$.

Here is a plot of $f$ ; the red segment shows the set $A$ :
[image: plot]

Comment: Is x = [1, 1] the correct answer?

Comment: I think you made a typo, this should be $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Yes it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Think about the numbers $x$ such that $-1\leq -x^2<4$.

Comment: Is x = [ -1, 1] the correct answer?

Comment: @PawelJezierski : Yes, it is!